# Is it a Wash Sale from a Capital Gains Perspective if I was to sell Nasdaq ETF and buy Nasdaq 100 ETF?

Tags: united-states, etf, capital-gains-tax, wash-sale, nasdaq

If I was to sell 100 units of ONEQ and use the proceeds to buy NDX, would I have any tax liability on the capital gains from a first sale or would it be considered a wash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it would most likely NOT be considered a wash sale because they are tracking different indexes (NDX in an index, not a fund, so I'm presuming that you're talking about a fund that tracks NDX like QQQ)

Second, wash sale rules only apply when selling at a *loss*, so if you're worrying about being taxed on a *gain*, then yes you would be liable for appropriate capital gains tax when you sell. There is no "wash sale" rule in the US to defer tax on *gains*, only *losses*.